# Knockout JS image binding

Tags: asp.net, knockout.js, asp.net-web-api

I am using knockout js in my single page application. I have a file upload input tag that I'm using knockout to upload the file with. In this case the files being uploaded are images.

Once the image has been processed by my ASP.NET Web API, and it comes back into my callback function I am inserting the response into an observable array which inhand updates the screen with the new image and text that was added.

However, for some reason the images aren't being displayed. If I refresh the page it loads the images fine but when adding to the observable array it's not showing the images.

Any ideas?

**Edit:** Here is my code that adds the item, it's pretty straight forward.

```
 item = {
                                "insightTypeId": 0,
                                "memberId": currentMemberId(),
                                "postedByMemberId": store.fetch("currentUser"),
                                "value": insight(),
                                "image": "content/insights/" + fileName
                            };

  messaging.client.addItem = function(item) {
        member().insights.unshift(item);
    };
```

**Update**

Forgot to mention that it works fine on a computer viewing the site, but on a phone it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you post your client-side code that's dealing with the updating?

Comment: I edited my post, it's pretty straight forward, I can't post anymore than that as this is for a client.

Comment: HI, I actually meant what you've added, but also the html with the knockout binding.

Comment: I figured out what is causing it, it's a mobile safari resource issue. Apparently I'm hitting the limit

Comment: you can answer your own question so it doesn't show in the list of unanswered questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that it was a mobile safari resource issue